# Strange things in count() results. Need clarification

Tags: python, pandas

I have the initial dataframe with the following structure (parameters in ETH1-ETH3 are thought up just for the example to show that each alarm has different set of ETH1-ETH3 parameters and can contain zeros):

```
       | Site |   Date   | Alarm | ETH1 | ETH2 | ETH 3|
       | AR21 | 25-01-19 |  AL1  |   1  |   0  |   3  |  
       | AR22 | 25-01-19 |  AL2  |   0  |   0  |   1  |
       | AR23 | 26-01-19 |  AL1  |   1  |   1  |   0  |  
       | AR21 | 26-01-19 |  AL2  |   0  |   1  |   0  |
```

I'm applying a groupby method and as a result I want to see how many times each ETH1-ETH3 parameter happend for each site for each alarm during the date.

```py
cols = ['Site', 'Date', 'Alarm']
df.groupby(cols)[['ETH1', 'ETH2', 'ETH3']].count()
```

This actually gives me the result that all alarms in all site per each day have "2" in all ETH1-ETH3 columns even if the particular site on this alarm had 0 at the column.

When I apply sum() I see, that those sites that had 0s in columns still have zeros. But why count() includes zeros in count?

How to achieve the output that if column has 0 it doesnt count, and count only occurences in columns that are greater than 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need replace `0` to `nan`s, because [`DataFrame.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) exclude missing values:

```
cols = ['Site', 'Date', 'Alarm']
df = df.mask(df == 0, np.nan).groupby(cols)['ETH1', 'ETH2', 'ETH3'].count()
print (df)
                     ETH1  ETH2  ETH3
Site Date     Alarm                  
AR21 25-01-19 AL1       1     0     1
     26-01-19 AL2       0     1     0
AR22 25-01-19 AL2       0     0     1
AR23 26-01-19 AL1       1     1     0
```

Another idea is convert boolean mask to integers and use `sum`:

```
cols = ['Site', 'Date', 'Alarm']
cols1 = ['ETH1', 'ETH2', 'ETH3']

df[cols1] = df[cols1].ne(0).astype('int')
df = df.groupby(cols)[cols1].sum()
print (df)
                     ETH1  ETH2  ETH3
Site Date     Alarm                  
AR21 25-01-19 AL1       1     0     1
     26-01-19 AL2       0     1     0
AR22 25-01-19 AL2       0     0     1
AR23 26-01-19 AL1       1     1     0
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation on how the count() method works and code. worked just perfect!